# Using vectors to initialize object arrays for parameterized constructors

Tags: c++, vector

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and am relatively new to C++. The program I am trying to work with has a class with a parameterized constructor and a destructor in its declaration. Somewhere in the listing, there was a dynamic object array creation using 'new'. However, I faced issues as object array initialization for parameterized constructors is not possible.

I have, thus, tried to implement vectors:

> std::vector< class_type > my_object_array(length, arg); //current attempt
>
> my_object_array = new class_type[length](arg); //previous code

However, once this object array is created, a ~vector destructor is called and I receive a runtime error of "Debug Assertion Failed... _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID (pHead->nBlockUse)"

Based on previous such questions on SO, I think this is because of double deletion but I have not called the destructor explicitly during the debugging steps and I still receive this error.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Added some snippets of the code with names changed.

```
class class_type {
  public:
    class_type(int var1);
    ~Class_type();
    /*

     Member functions

    */
  private:
    int var1;                        
    double var2;                   
    double length;                 
    double width;
    double* arr1;                  
};
```

Constructor definition:

```
Class_type::Class_type(int il){
  length    = 0;
  width     = 0;
  var1    = il;
  var2   = 5;
  arr1 = new double[5];
}
```

Destructor definition:

```
  Class_type::~Class_type(){
   
  delete [] arr1;}
```

Code where error occurs:

```
int class_type_2::create_my_objects(int num_elem){
   input_value = 10;
   if ( num_elem == 0 ) {
      std::cout<<"Warning!"<<endl;
   } else {
      std::vector<class_type> my_object_array(num_elem, input_value);
      //my_object_array= new class_type[num_elem](input_value);
        } //Debugger doesn't go beyond this step!
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: We need a proper [mcve], there is not enough information in just 1 line of code

Comment: Without some actual code we can't see what's wrong..

Comment: @UnholySheep some code added. Sorry, I had to skin it as I am not allowed to share the source code (company policy).

Comment: Please read the link I provided in my comment carefully. The code you posted is not a [mcve], we cannot compile it ourselves to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector my_object_array(length, arg); //current attempt
```

Your vector might be out of scope as much as you wrote is just one line. So, it's not possible to reply exact cause what happened to yours. I think you might pass the vector to another copy constructor or move constructor where it deletes the memory and calls the destructor.

As @Matthieu Brucher just said you should manage memory by yourself if allocated using "new". Otherwise double deletion is a common issue and may other memory issues may occur.

Edit1:
I just updated after seeing your code

```
std::vector<class_type> my_object_array(num_elem, input_value);
} ---> when this scope hits it will release all stacked memory inside it and call their object constructors
```

Initialize the raw pointer with nullptr.

```
double* arr1; // you have written
double* arr1 = nullptr;  // recommended
```

Edit 2:

you can delete a memory if allocated with malloc() or calloc(). otherwise use vector. it will manage your memory without leak.

Comment: The error happens because the vector will copy the original objects and then would trigger the deletion of the allocated memory. Just using a vector will trigger the memory crash.

Comment: Primitive type memory associated to a non-primitive type destroys automatically. If you do malloc() to a pointer you have to free by yourself. Here the the class_type object is created implicitly into the vector and this vector is created into the stack of calling method. So when the scope reaches out the vector destroys and it's containing object collection by calling their destructors. vector is not a primitive type so it takes care of releasing it's own and it's container type memory as well where an array of object does not do that. In that case the object have to delete its heap memories.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `std::unique_ptr` for your object instead of the `double*`, you will see that your code doesn't compile anymore. This indicates that the code you have uses the default copy constructor, and the pointer will be copied to a copied class.

Unfortunately, this means that several objects will have the same pointer and try to free it, which will fail. If you follow good c++ practices and never call `new` and `delete` yourself, you won't see these issues anymore, because they will force you to think properly from the start.

Comment: Thanks! In the actual code, the `double* ` takes an array of variable length. If not allocated dynamically, how else can this be instantiated?

Comment: Use a vector, for instance!

Comment: But you can have variable length arrays with unique pointers, and this would make you understand the actual memory error you have.